# Installing GDAL and Fiona on Python 3.7/3.8 and (W10)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, gdal, fiona

I unfortunately can't manage to install Fiona on Windows 10.

What I have tried:

1. Installing Python 3.7
2. Installing GDAL according to https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows chosing GDAL core and Python bindings for 3.7
3. Adding everything to Path
4. Installing the Fiona wheel from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (tried installing the "right" GDAL wheel beforehand, too).

I've also tried with the recent Python (3.8.5) as well as installing it with conda to no avail. When going for the Python route, I always seem to be getting the same error when I'm trying to import Fiona and as far as I understand it seems to be connected to my GDAL installation but I can't figure it out and it's the second day of trying. The frustration level is over 9000 at this point and I can't figure out what to do. However, this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: Couldn't find module. (this line is translated)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://colab.research.google.com/ which works same as Jupyter Notebook in Anacoda. With that you just have to do `pip install gdal or !pip install gdal`